# SQL Server Agent stop, start, pause, restart buttons are all disabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Can anyone know why all the buttons are disabled ?

I am trying to create a Job on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe the SQL Agent is included in SQL Express.  With SQL 2008, MS started including the creation of the service but I believe it is disabled by default and cannot be started.

Comment: You mean Sql server Jobs are not supported in Express Edition ?

Comment: @Joseph, yes that is what Jeff said.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff is correct, SQL server agent is not included in any of the express editions of SQL server. You can however still schedule tasks using a combination of sqlcmd and windows task scheduler. It’s a bit crude but does the job!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

Go to run type services.msc

Right click on the SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)

Then check in the properties your startup type might be disabled change it to automatic or manual and try again it will enable the start option